# Printing big numbers in c++

Tags: c++, math, double

Take the following code in c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h> 
using namespace std; 

int main(){
  double one, out;
 
  one = (pow(10, 10) - 1 ) / 9; //1111111111 
  out = one  * pow(10, 12) + one * 80 + 9;
  cout << fixed << out << endl;
}
```

it returns

```
1111111111088888872960.000000
```

Variable `out` should equal `1111111111088888888889`.

When I paste the following formula in https://www.wolframalpha.com, that equals varialble `one` 
`(10^10 - 1)/9 * 10^12 + 80 * (10^10 - 1)/9 + 9` the result is correct.
Could you tell me where I did a mistake?

Comment: You probably need a big math library to match that.

Comment: Considering the nature of normal floating point types, the answer is 
 99,999999999999998566% correct

Comment: As for arbitrary precise math, you could use https://gmplib.org/ or https://www.mpfr.org/